# System information shown when booting Debian

Tags: linux, boot, debian

When booting Debian, you'll see it printing a lot of information about the system variables and such.

I don't really need to see all that, so I'd like to modify some scripts to make sure that on boot, it just does what it has to do, without printing it on the screen. Just something I fancy.

Offcourse, still seeing errors would be nice. But that long slur of text, I could do without.

I've tried looking it up, but I can't find documentation on this specific thing anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for [splashy](http://splashy.alioth.debian.org/wiki/). Most modern desktop distributions come with some kind of graphical boot pre-configured (or easily installable) and fallback to displaying text when some error happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting `quiet` on the kernel line in grub config.

Comment: It's already there.